# Web.Config of silverlight application vs Web.Config of Silverlight hosting application

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, web-config

I created a new silverlight business application. Thus I have two projects in the solution, one is silverlight application and silverlight hosting web application. Each project has its own web.config file. Kindly enlighten me what is the difference between those two config files.

I am strucked at the following place, owing to lack of awareness.

I want to consume a WCF service, which uses a MySQL DB. So, which web.config is the ideal place to define connection strings and role providers. Any thumb rule will be much appreciated

Edit 1:: How to decide the ideal place among those two files for other configurations. Which configuration goes to which web.config file. (pls spare with the unclear edit)

Answer (score 0):

u should place ur connection string at the server-side of ur solution. client application should`t know anything about the database and others processes, relating to the server. 
Client(silverlight app.) should consume WCF requesting needed data.

P.S. within the client`s app.config u can place, for example, a logger configuration(coz every client should write his own log), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup. On the ASP.Net side of the project where the WCF service lives, put your connection strings in that web.config file. The Silverlight portion of the project is not trusted, as it will exist out in the wild where anyone can take it apart. The config file on the Silverlight side is where you specify your service references that will talk to the ASP.Net side.